# How can I make ng-show test for the existance of some property value in an array?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following array:

```
[{"action":"Start","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":2},
 {"action":"Archive","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":6},
 {"action":"Hide","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":7},
 {"action":"Delete","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":8},
 {"action":"Mark","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":5},
 {"action":"Grade","currentStatus":1,"newStatus":4}]
```

In my HTML code I was using a repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="control in home.$ts.controls">
   <button 
      id="start"
      ng-click="home.$ts.startTest()"
      ng-disable="home.$ts.action"
      ng-show="control.action == 'Start'">
      Start
   </button>
   <button 
      id="stop"
      ng-click="home.$ts.stopTest()"
      ng-disable="home.$ts.action"
      ng-show="control.action == 'Stop'">
      Stop
   </button>
</div>
```

This works but I now realize this actually gives me six elements with an id="start" and six with an id="stop"

Is there another way that I could do this without the ng-repeat so that for the ng-show I just check for 
the existance of the action 'Start' in the home.$ts.controls and if it exists then show that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace ng-show with ng-if

```
<div ng-repeat="control in home.$ts.controls">
   <button 
      id="start"
      ng-click="home.$ts.startTest()"
      ng-disable="home.$ts.action"
      ng-if="control.action == 'Start'">
      Start
   </button>
   <button 
      id="stop"
      ng-click="home.$ts.stopTest()"
      ng-disable="home.$ts.action"
      ng-if="control.action == 'Stop'">
      Stop
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Would that still not result in the button element being added to the DOM for every row in the home.$ts.controls?

Comment: no, ng-if is different from ng-show, it does add/remove element from DOM based on bool condtion... ng-show/ng-hide keep them in DOM just shows/hides them...

Answer (score 0):

You could find the required actions in the array and set them on the scope. This solution uses [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which should be polyfilled for older browsers:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function( $scope ) {
  
    function action(name){
      var actions = $scope.actions.filter(function(action){
        return action.action === name;
      });
      
      return actions.length > 0 ? actions[0] : null;
    }
  
    $scope.actions = [
     {"action":"Start"},
     {"action":"Archive"},
     {"action":"Hide"},
     {"action":"Delete"},
     {"action":"Mark"},
     {"action":"Grade"}
    ];
  
    $scope.start = action('Start');
    $scope.stop = action('Stop');
    $scope.archive = action('Archive')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
   <button ng-show='start != null'>{{start.action}}</button>
   <button ng-show='stop != null'>{{stop.action}}</button>
   <button ng-show='archive != null'>{{archive.action}}</button>
</div>
```